# Are Federal Holidays business days?

Tags: florida

[FS718 indicates:](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0700-0799/0718/Sections/0718.111.html)

> The failure of an association to provide the records within 10 **working**
> days after receipt of a written request creates a rebuttable
> presumption that the association willfully failed to comply with this
> paragraph

1. Do **working** days exclude Saturday and Sunday?
2. Do **working** days exclude Federal Holidays (i.e. Columbus Day)
3. Any other exclusions?

Any references or equivalent of case law are appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: If it included those, it would say "calendar days"...

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Do working days exclude Saturday and Sunday?

Yes.

> 2. Do working days exclude Federal Holidays (i.e. Columbus Day)

Probably. It would be less clear in Colorado in the particular case of Columbus Day which is a federal holiday but not a state or local holiday, but this would probably be unambiguous in Florida which does not make that distinction.

> 3. Any other exclusions?

Probably any state holidays that are not federal holidays, and any days where natural disasters like hurricanes prevent businesses and courts from opening in the place where the events are taking place.

[Florida Rule of Judicial Administration 2.514](https://casetext.com/rule/florida-court-rules/florida-rules-of-judicial-administration/part-v-practice-of-lawa/practice-and-litigation-procedures/rule-2514-computing-and-extending-time), would probably be controlling if there is no other definition in the statute, since the question appears to be calculating a statutory time period. It states:

> Rule 2.514 - COMPUTING AND EXTENDING TIME
>
> (a) Computing Time. T**he following rules apply in computing time
> periods specified in any** rule of procedure, local rule, court order,
> or **statute that does not specify a method of computing time.**
>
> (1) Period Stated in Days or a Longer Unit. When the period is stated
> in days or a longer unit of time:
>
> (A) begin counting from the next day that is not a Saturday, Sunday,
> or legal holiday;
>
> (B) count every day, including intermediate Saturdays, Sundays, and
> legal holidays; and
>
> (C) include the last day of the period, but if the last day is a
> Saturday, Sunday, or legal holiday, or falls within any period of time
> extended through an order of the chief justice under Florida Rule of
> Judicial Administration 2.205(a)(2)(B)(iv), the period continues to
> run until the end of the next day that is not a Saturday, Sunday, or
> legal holiday and does not fall within any period of time extended
> through an order of the chief justice.
>
> (2) Period Stated in Hours. When the period is stated in hours
>
> (A) begin counting immediately on the occurrence of the event that
> triggers the period;
>
> (B) count every hour, including hours during intermediate Saturdays,
> Sundays, and legal holidays; and
>
> (C) if the period would end on a Saturday, Sunday, or legal holiday,
> or during any period of time extended through an order of the chief
> justice under Florida Rule of Judicial Administration
> 2.205(a)(2)(B)(iv), the period continues to run until the same time on the next day that is not a Saturday, Sunday, or legal holiday and does
> not fall within any period of time extended through an order of the
> chief justice.
>
> (3) Period Stated in Days Less Than Seven Days. When the period stated
> in days is less than 7 days, intermediate Saturdays, Sundays, and
> legal holidays shall be excluded in the computation.
>
> (4) "Last Day" Defined. Unless a different time is set by a statute,
> local rule, or court order, the last day ends
>
> (A) for electronic filing or for service by any means, at midnight;
> and
>
> (B) for filing by other means, when the clerk's office is scheduled to
> close.
>
> (5) "Next Day" Defined. The "next day" is determined by continuing to
> count forward when the period is measured after an event and backward
> when measured before an event.
>
> (6) "Legal Holiday" Defined. "Legal holiday" means
>
> (A) **the day set aside by section 110.117, Florida Statutes, for
> observing New Year's Day, Martin Luther King, Jr.'s Birthday, Memorial
> Day, Independence Day, Labor Day, Veterans' Day, Thanksgiving Day, the
> Friday after Thanksgiving Day, or Christmas Day,** and
>
> (B) **any day observed as a holiday by the clerk's office or as
> designated by the chief judge.**
>
> (b) Additional Time after Service by Mail. When a party may or must
> act within a specified time after service and service is made by mail,
> 5 days are added after the period that would otherwise expire under
> subdivision (a).